# How can I get the UserID of a person from a split version of their First/Last Name from FullName in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a Check-in/out system.

So far I have a dropdown that get the list of active events.

```
<select name="events">

<?php

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'user', 'pw', 'database') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $eveny = $conn->query("select event_title from events_event where inactive=0");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($eveny)) {
                  unset($event);
                  $event = $row['event_title']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$event.'">'.$event.'</option>';

}
?>
</select>
```

And a textbox that searches users based on first name, but it auto displays results (like a Google search) and then fills out the info with both First Name and Last name. [Source.](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php)

The only change in the php is the echo to show both first and last names as follows:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<p>" . $row["per_FirstName"] . " " . $row["per_LastName"] . "</p>";
            }
```

**NOW FOR THE PROBLEM**

I have made the frontend into a form, and a submit button using method="post".

But something in my php is not functioning/lacking.

```
<?php
   $db = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'user', 'pw', 'database') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
   session_start();
      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $myname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['fullname']);
  $eventy = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['events']);

  //$checktime = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
  $evid = "SELECT event_id from events_event where event_title = '$eventy'";
  $revvy = mysqli_query($db,$evid);
  $nameParts = explode(' ', $myname);
  $firstName = trim($nameParts[0]);
  $lastName = trim($nameParts[1]);
  $sql = "SELECT per_ID FROM person_per WHERE per_FirstName = '$firstName' AND per_LastName = '$lastName'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  //$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  //$result = $result->fetch_all();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $perID = $row['per_ID'];
  }
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($revvy)){
    $evvy = $row['event_ID'];
  }
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  // table row must be 1 row if it succeeded
 if($count == 1) {
     //session_register("myname");
     //$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myname;
     $checkin = "insert into event_attend (attend_id, event_id, person_id, checkin_date) values (DEFAULT, '$evvy', '$perID', now())" or die(mysqli_error());;
     mysqli_query($db,$checkin);
     header("location: checkedin.php");
  }else {
         $error = "An error occurred.";

      }
   }
?>
```

The $myname, is the result of both first name and last name, I need just First Name based on the filled out text field which uses both first and last names.

I also can't get the Event_ID from the  dropdown.

Comment: I think in this line: $checkin = "insert into event_attend (attend_id, person_id, checkin_date) values (NULL, '$result2', '$result', now())";, you added 3 column names and 4 values. May be this causes an issue. Please add 4 column names and 4 values. and try once.

Comment: At this line: $active = $row['active']; you are trying to get a column which you didn't fetch (you fetch only id)

Comment: Why not give them a unique username and password- like every other login system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user's first and last name are separated by space:

```
$nameParts = explode(' ', $myname);
$firstName = trim($nameParts[0]);
```

Comment: thank you, with this i got first name, and also got last name by using: $lastName = trim($nameParts[1]);